# how do i display listview with jdbc

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iputs.png)am trying to get String and image url from database and display it on `ListView` using JDBC, the application every time show application force stop.

I tried to display the string on Toast and it's working 100%.
I am not sure where is the problem but i guess it's on View Holder, or on access the `TextView` and `ImageView`.

```
   public class Viewholder{TextView textView; ImageView imageView;  } 
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        View  rowView=convertView;
        Viewholder viewholder=null ;
        if (rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();              rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content,parent,false);
            viewholder =new Viewholder();
            viewholder.imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewholder.textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
           rowView.setTag(viewholder);
            name=parkinglist.get(position).getName();
           Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            viewholder =(Viewholder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        //i have error in next lines **************      
  viewholder.textView.setText(parkinglist.get(position).getName()+"");  Picasso.with(context).load(parkinglist.get(position).getImg()).into(viewholder.imageView);
        return rowView;  }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.kiddo.listview, PID: 17130
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.example.kiddo.listview.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:174)
>                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
>                         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>                         at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>                         at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>                         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>                         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1768)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5694)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your "force stop" crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: i added the force stop error i understand nothing

Comment: it's shows the error from get view is there is other method to get view ?

Comment: what is the `R` in `R.layout.list_content`?

Comment: The R.layout member is a auto-generated class that contains all IDs for layouts i dont think this is the problem dude.